# Linenumber for Exception thrown in runtime-compiled DotNET code

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace, line-numbers

Not quite the same as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056100/determining-which-code-line-threw-the-exception), but pretty close.

My program allows people to enter some VB or C# code which gets compiled, loaded and executed at runtime. My CompilerParams are:

```
CompilerParameters params = new CompilerParameters();
params.GenerateExecutable = false;
params.GenerateInMemory = true;
params.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
params.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
params.WarningLevel = 4;
```

When this code throws an exception I'd like to be able to display a message box that helps users debug their code. The exception message is easy, but the line-number is where I got stuck.

I suspect that in order to get at the line number, I may need to drastically change the CompilerParameters and perhaps even the way these dlls get stored/loaded.

Does anyone know the least steps needed to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set OutputAssembly to a temp file, set GenerateInMemory = false, IncludeDebugInformation = true
That should generate symbols and allow you to get a full stack trace with code lines

Comment: Thanks Tom, I was afraid that was the answer. Now I have to figure out a way to delete all those dll and pdb files *after* my application shuts down... Any ideas on that?

Comment: just create them in the Windows Temp directory so windows takes care of it: Path.GetTempFileName()

Comment: That's where I put them, but that folder is close to 1 Gig on my machine, if someone is taking care of it they're doing a sloppy job...

Comment: hm, Windows might not clean that up until it 'feels' it has to. You could always create a separate folder and set the OutputAssembly = "mytempfolder" + Path.GetRandomFileName()  
Then just clean it up everytime the application launches or shuts down

Comment: That's a good solution. The File delete will fail if there is still an instance of my app that is using a dll, so I can wipe all unused dlls in my own temp folder on run.

Comment: Windows doesn't automatically clean up files placed in the Temp directory. `Path.GetTempFileName()` only generates a temporary file; it does nothing to clean up when you're done using it. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).